# How to write unit test case for GET http verb in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test case for AngularJs Post operation. I have created mock service. I am trying to write test case as below.

Below are the input fields to pass as model.

```
userid,tenantid,username,emailaddress.
```

Below is the service I created.

```
 addUser<T>(): Observable<T> {
        var addUserResult = { result: true } as any;
        return Observable.of<T>(addUserResult);
    }
```

Below is the test case I am trying to invoke post operation.

```
it('should add the users', fakeAsync(() => {

}));
```

Can someone help me to write the above test case? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.